# Self-Driving at Kruger National Park: Are there rental car services in or near the park?

Tags: budget, car-rentals, south-africa, safari, kruger-national-park

My family and I are ecstatic about our S. Africa trip next year. We are on a tour bus company (Expat Explore), and we have three free days at Kruger National Park (not nearly enough!). We have questions about the feasibility and practicality of **self-driving in Kruger** (in the interest of saving money for our family).

I know that the Park's hours are 6am-6pm, and in order to see the animals at their most active, you have to go on a Dawn & Dusk safari tour with a trained guide. We will be doing that.

However, during the daytime.... we still wanna explore this massive and beautiful park. I know there are safari packages for the day, but they are far above our budget, and we read that it was cheaper to just rent your own car and drive yourself than pay a safari (where you'll be crammed with strangers, on their schedule, and not the best visibility in a long van where windows don't open).

**Are there rental car places in and around Kruger National Park??**  Our Bus Company takes us and **drops us off** West of Kruger at our accommodation **Bundu Lodge** in **Nelspruit** (and I believe they just assume everyone will pay for the safaris -- even in the day), but I read that self-driving is much cheaper and preferred -- I just don't know if these comments I've been reading are from people living in South Africa or rented a car much further out and drove them into the park...

**Can one just rent a car when they get to the National Park? Are there a few companies in Nelspruit area?** Preferably, nearest to Bundu Lodge?? Since we'll be without a car (and there isn't public transportation that I know of), we will probably have to walk to the nearest rental place from Bundu Lodge.

*The roads, for the most part, are paved or have dirt roads that are free of rocks, etc., right?*

Comment: Where will you be departing your tour from for these 3 days? Within Kruger eg Skukuza? Or outside like Graskop?

Comment: (I've been twice as in my other answer, once as a SA citizen, once as a foreign tourist.  Both times we've self driven and done one or two drives and it was worth it)

Comment: @MarkMayo, yes... we will be staying in Skukuza! Are there rental cars near this area? (Yes, I've heard wonderful things about self-driving vs. safari guides). Where did you pick up your rental?

Comment: Heh, I picked up our rental in Cape Town (a Toyota Condor), so doesn't help too much in that regard.  We drove all around. The first time it was our own car.
If you rent, try to get a high car (eg a 4wd), the roads are fine, but sometimes the high grass is a problem in a sedan.

Comment: @MarkMayo, thanks for your help. I'll certainly looking for a high 4wd. However, I got a bit more information. I am staying in the Bundu Lodge in Nelspruit.  I'm hoping there is a car rental place in walking distance from the Bundu Lodge!! *fingers crossed*

Comment: Aha, Nelspruit's not that small, so [there are fortunately quite a few rental places there to look at](http://www.southafrica.to/transport/carrentals/car-rentals-nelspruit/car-rentals-Nelspruit-airport.php5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the park, at Skukuza, there [is an Avis rent a car](https://www.avis.com/en/locations/za/kruger-national-park/szk).  Since some tourists fly into Skukuza, it's convenient for this to exist.

Prices will vary depending on time of year and your requirements, and we don't tend to permit price-shopping answers on here as things change constantly, but have a look and see what you can find.

From my experience, a vehicle like a [Toyota Condor was fantastic](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=toyota+condor&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR8O2hsZ7VAhXGT7wKHbRoAVYQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=666).